# JS helper stops working after I added prefix to action

Tags: php, cakephp

I have controller with an *add* action.

```
public function add() {   
    $this->layout = 'manage';
    $this->set($this->Restaurant->fetchRelatedData());
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $this->Restaurant->create();
        if ($this->Restaurant->save($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash('ok!');
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash('Error!');
        }
    }
}
```

View for this action created with Form and Js helpers:

```
echo $this->Form->create('Restaurant');
// some fields
echo $this->Form->input('district_id', array('label' => 'District'));
echo $this->Form->input('street_id', array('label' => 'Street')); 
// other fields
echo $this->Form->end(array('label' => 'Add'));

$this->Js->get('#RestaurantDistrictId')->event('change', 
$this->Js->request(array(
    'controller'=>'streets',
    'action'=>'getByDistrict'
    ), array(
    'update'=>'#RestaurantStreetId',
    'async' => true,
    'method' => 'post',
    'dataExpression'=>true,
    'data'=> $this->Js->serializeForm(array(
        'isForm' => true,
        'inline' => true
        ))
    ))
);
```

Js helper shows list with streets that are in choosen district.

StreetsController -> getByDistrict action:

```
public function getByDistrict(){
    $district_id = $this->request->data['Restaurant']['district_id'];
    $streets = $this->Street->find('list', array(
        'conditions' => array('Street.district_id' => $district_id),
        'fields' => array('street'),
        'order' => array('Street'),
        'recursive' => -1,
    ));
    $this->set('streets', $streets);
    $this->layout = 'ajax';
}
```

Everything worked fine until I added the administrative prefix to this action.
If action is named *public function add()* – all things works.
If action is named *public function admin_add()* – Js helper stops updating streets list on district change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure on this, but I believe that the JS helper is preserving the admin prefix when it makes the AJAX request. When in add() it would call getByDistrict(). When in admin_add() it would call admin_getByDistrict(). Try passing 'admin' => false into Js->request.

Comment: Thank you! I suspected something like that. Now the problem is solved.